# Using BASH, how would one use wc -l on a variable set to the output of a find command?

Tags: bash

Warning: I'm a noob.
Anyway, if I have var `foo=$(find / \( -name "Test.txt" \))`, and knowing that using that same find command and piping the output to wc -l gives me the correct result count; how would I count the results using just `foo`(not another find)?bash

Comment: (OT: You don't need `\( … \)` in that `find` command.)

Comment: @chepner - you are absolutely right. I kept forgetting to quote `"` it. I'll remove my previous comment because it's misleading.

Comment: You can't do this very easily if you want 100% accuracy. File names can contain both spaces and newlines, which will mess with any of the provided answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a "here string":

```
wc -l <<<"$foo"
```

(See [§3.6.6 "Here Documents" and §3.6.7 "Here Strings" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents).)

Comment: Hmmm... I've tried that, but it keeps returning 1 no matter what.  echo "Found files:" Lang=$( find / -name "*.lproj" -not -name "en*" -not -name "En*" -not -name "Base*" ) wc -l <<<"$Lang" rm -r $Lang >/dev/null 2>&1     #I have no idea what im doing wrong...

Comment: @Nocturnal: Try running `echo "$Lang"` . . .

Comment: ya, its finding the files and all properly, but only seperates them with spaces, which im assuming in the problem.

Comment: @Nocturnal: So, you'll want to find the root cause of that. The code that you posted in your comment looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you can use a here string:

```
wc -l <<<"$foo"
```

Traditionally, you'd have to separately pipe it:

```
printf "%s\n" "$foo" | wc -l
```

However, storing large results in a variable is a construct I recommend avoiding if you can.  If the goal (as suggested in some of your comments) is to delete the files you found and report how many were deleted, I'd do something like

```
find / -name "*.lproj" -not -name "en*" -not -name "En*" \
  -not -name "Base*" -printf '.' -delete |
wc -c |
sed 's/.*/Found and deleted & files./'
```

(If your `find` does not support `-printf`and `-delete` -- which are GNU `find` extensions -- you'll need to `-exec` some external utilities.  Then perhaps you'll want to refactor the whole snippet to something which runs inside a simple shell script.)

Comment: Hmmm... I've tried that, but it keeps returning 1 no matter what.  echo "Found files:" Lang=$( find / -name "*.lproj" -not -name "en*" -not -name "En*" -not -name "Base*" ) wc -l <<<"$Lang" rm -r $Lang >/dev/null 2>&1     #I have no idea what im doing wrong...

Comment: What's in the string then?

Comment: If `foo` is empty, you'll still get a line count of 1 because here strings are implicitly terminated by a newline.